# ScrolledPageBook alternative?

Tags: java, swt, jface, rcp

Is there a native SWT or RCP component which has the same behaviour than a [ScrolledPageBook](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/forms/widgets/ScrolledPageBook.html) which is not a part of Forms API ?

My need is to change dynamically the content of a View. For example, i would like do something like :

```
Composite content1;
Composite content2;
Composite content3;    
myView.showContent(content1); // Draw the content1 into the view client area
myView.showContent(content2); // Draw the content1 with content2
myView.showContent(content3); // Draw the content2 with content3
```

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think of `TabFolder` if you are looking for only Native SWT widget.

RCP:  `org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBook`

Comment: I would be interested in RCP component too (I'm updating my post)